# Hyperlinking in QGIS - Add Data to current window

Tags: qgis, python

I am looking to add to my current action in QGIS so that a hyperlinked file will open in the current QGIS window, rather than in a new window.  Here is what my action looks like:

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Quantum GIS Wroclaw/apps/qgis/bin/qgis.exe" "C:\Users\Ryan Garnett\Dropbox\SpatialData\Imagery\Landsat\%Image"
```

I am hoping I can use this as a means to share data so that users can load in satellite images basked on a click with the Hotlinks plugin.

---

Thanks Nathan,
I tried this, but it did not load the file.  It came back with the following error:

```
C:\Users\Ryan Garnett\Dropbox\SpatialData\Imagery\Landsat8020_nad83_utm_30m_123457.jp2 is not a valid or recognized raster data source
```

This is what I have written in the action:

```
qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer("C:\Users\Ryan Garnett\Dropbox\SpatialData\Imagery\Landsat\%Image")
```

With is set to Python. I have noticed in the error that there isn't a \ in between Landsat and the file name, plus the file name has been cut short, from **028020_nad83**... to **Landsat8020_nad83**...

Any thoughts?  My other way is still working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can open a layer in the current instance with a bit of python code in the layer action.

```
qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer("C:\Users\Ryan Garnett\Dropbox\SpatialData\Imagery\Landsat\%Image")
```

Switch the action type to **Python** .

Reference for interface object http://qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html

Comment: I figured it out.  You needed to change all the \ to \\ for Python.  qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer("C:\\Users\\Ryan Garnett\\Dropbox\\SpatialData\\Imagery\\Landsat\\%Image")