# Hyperlinking to PostGIS Layers and Zip files with QGIS Actions

Tags: qgis, postgis

I previously asked a question about hyperlinking data in QGIS that gets loaded into QGIS (see post: [Hyperlinking in QGIS - Add Data to current window](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23906/hyperlinking-in-qgis-add-data-to-current-window)).  A user provided me with the code, which works perfectly [Python qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer("C:\Users\Ryan Garnett\Dropbox\SpatialData\Imagery\Landsat\%Image")].

I am hoping to modify this code so that I can do two different actions:
1) Load data from a PostGIS Database
2) Have a zip file saved to a location on a local computer

I have data stored in a PostGIS database (ie: LUGDC as the Database, basedata as the Schema, bound_poly as the Table).  In some instances there may be points, lines and polygons for the regon, so I am thinking of an Action for each of the geometry types.

With regards to the zip files, I have the files in a shared location, but I would like to have it so the file is copied from that location to a specified location on a local machine through an action.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the copy action you can use a action with **Type**:Windows and a **Action** of:

```
cmd /c copy {your file location} {dest}
```

e.g.

```
cmd /c copy C:\Temp\250mmContours.shp C:\
```

Will copy 250mmContours from C:\Temp to C:\

And for PostGIS have a action with **Type**:`Python` and **Action** text of:

```
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "postgis", "{username}", "{your password}")
uri.setDataSource("public", "{layer}", "{geom column}", "")
qgis.utils.iface.addVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "layer_name_you_like", "postgres")
```

like so:

```
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "postgis", "postgres", "xxxxxxxx")
uri.setDataSource("public", "signs", "the_geom", "")
qgis.utils.iface.addVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "layer_name_you_like", "postgres")
```

Obviously replacing any values you need with a expession inside `[% {expression} %]`

You can even do something like this to load the three layers at once:

```
def loadLayer(name):
    uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
    uri.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "postgis", "postgres", "xxxxx")
    uri.setDataSource("public", name, "the_geom", "")
    qgis.utils.iface.addVectorLayer(uri.uri(), name, "postgres")

loadLayer("layer1")
loadLayer("layer2")
loadLayer("layer3")
```

Comment: No worries.  I'm thinking I might turn it into a blog post because it is pretty cool.

Comment: BTW if you don't mind what use case do you have for doing something like this?

Comment: Thanks again Nathan.  What I am using it for is a way for university students, faculty and researchers to access geospatial data via computer on and off campus.  We have terabytes of data, with many layers over a very large geographic extent.  Many of our users need the raw data for their work, so I wanted to have it organized in a means where they didn't need to load all the data at once.  I have a database that has tile extents, which users will use to load vectors and raster.  Now they can have the raw data saved to a folder.