# Hyperlinking multiple PDFs to multiple points using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, pdf, hyperlink

I would like to hyperlink a PDF to a point. Each point will have a link to a different PDF. So far it seems that I can do it one by one.

Is there a quicker way of doing it?

We're using ArcMap.

Answer (score 4):

The way I have done it in ArcMap is the following (note that it may be a little different if you are using an older version, I am using 10.0).

- In your attribute table add a field with the absolute path to the PDF files
  (ie: c:\Temp\PDFs\Document1.pdf)
- With the shapefile you want to use as the linking file allow hyperlinking according to a  field

  - Open the properties of the file
  - Go to Display
  - Check Support Hyperlinks using field
  - Choose the field that stores the absolute path to the pdf
  - Click OK
- To access the PDFs from the hyperlink field you will want to use the Hyperlink button (the lightning bolt)

Answer (score 3):

The software will be very important to know.  Here are two posts that explain how to do something very simular as Actions in QGIS.

[Hyperlinking in QGIS - Add Data to current window](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23906/hyperlinking-in-qgis-add-data-to-current-window)

[Hyperlinking to PostGIS Layers and Zip files with QGIS Actions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35560/hyperlinking-to-postgis-layers-and-zip-files-with-qgis-actions)