# How to create a photo-documentation in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, photos

I would like to create a photo-documentation in QGIS for some real world objects. The photos aren't geotagged but I now their position on the map. If possible I would like to link them to a point shape. How can I manage this? Would it be possible by means of a database connection using a BLOB datatype or are there other methods?

Comment: You can do this using hyperlinks.

See this post.

[http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34631/how-to-link-to-external-files-with-relative-path-in-qgis-actions][1]


  [1]: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34631/how-to-link-to-external-files-with-relative-path-in-qgis-actions

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a hyperlink to a pdf file in the attribute table](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88593/create-a-hyperlink-to-a-pdf-file-in-the-attribute-table)

Answer (score 2):

You can use actions as a method of opening and interacting with data. Actions allow you to "click" on a feature in a map, the QGIS active window, to load, open, or other actions, data from specified locations. These links will provide you with information on how to use actions to open and load data from QGIS: 
     [Hyperlinking to PostGIS Layers and Zip files with QGIS Actions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35560/hyperlinking-to-postgis-layers-and-zip-files-with-qgis-actions)
     [Hyperlinking in QGIS - Add Data to current window](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23906/hyperlinking-in-qgis-add-data-to-current-window)